# Populate all contacts with SDE data

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm wondering how synchronised data is loaded into all contacts.

Does the data from the synchronized data extension automatically land in all contacts? Or do you need to create an attribute group where the 'Contact Id' links to the 'Contact Key' in the synchronised data extension."

And do such contacts then have Source = "Import" in all contacts list?